# how to change actionbarsherlock menu item font face when using custom theme for actionbar?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

When I am using default sherlock light theme I can change the font face through this method (it can be cast to TextView)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new LayoutInflater.Factory() {
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                AttributeSet attrs) {

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")
                    || name.equalsIgnoreCase("TextView")) {
                try {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            // here I can change the font!
                            ((TextView)view).setTypeface(MY_CUSTOM_TYPE_FACE);
                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                } catch (InflateException e) {
                    // Handle any inflation exception here
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // Handle any ClassNotFoundException here
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

[image: actiobarsherlock with default light theme]

but when I use custom theme with [this tool](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), the above solution does not work. In this way each item is an instance of ActionMenuItemView and I do not know how to apply font face to it.

[image: actiobarsherlock with custom theme]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

need to create a custom menu view

```
  private ActionBar setCustomView(ActionBar actionBar,String title, String subtitle,boolean isSubTitleEnable){
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customer_view, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cust_action_bar_title);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "YOURFONT.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    tv.setText(title);


    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, actionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
  return actionBar; 
 }
```